# Run Play project from sbt

Tags: scala, build, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I am about to publish a Play project to github, but I would like that Scala developers don't need to install *play* separately if they already have *sbt* installed.

Would it be possible to compile and run a Play project with sbt if we add the correct dependencies ?

My working *build.sbt* for Play is here, but it doesn't work with sbt.

```
import play.Project._

name := "my_project_name"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.netflix.rxjava" % "rxjava-scala" % "0.17.4",
  "oauth.signpost" % "signpost-core" % "1.2.1.2",
  "oauth.signpost" % "signpost-commonshttp4" % "1.2.1.2",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.3.3",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.3"
)

playScalaSettings
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just should add the following line to `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3") // or your play version
```

`play new` does this by default.

You may check if the project is executable by sbt by executing `sbt run` from the terminal.